# Airflow/DBT reset stream

Tags: stream, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

I'm using stream this way in a model

```
FROM {{ sdp.streaming_source('<mySchema>', '<myTable>') }}
```

Then run it in a Airflow DAG

Now I would like to full-refresh it. But seems like the stream hasn't been reset.

How to reset/purge the stream?